# Google Sign-In API script error on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-oauth

My site allows people to log in using their Google account, everything works fine on other browsers except IE version 7 & 10.

When the homepage is loaded, there is an "Script error" displaying. I have no clue what to look into with such general error message. Detail message is below:

```
 
Line: 0
Char: 1
Error: Script error
Code: 0
URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=[mysitedomain]
```

I tried to disable Script parsing feature, then run the site again. Now it shows like below

```
Line: 839
Char: 1
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code: 0
URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=[mysitedomain]
```

I open the link in browser but it does not display anything.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

For someone who might run into this error

Seems like an **oauth2 iframe** has been added to my page dynamically.

And this iframe loads some other scripts. One of those script causes the error.

I think Google Log-in API library does not support **IE 7** because I tried to run a few other websites which support log-in with Google and there is an error also.

Anyway, I could not find any information on Google document page regarding the browser version they support.